# Change histogram across to left

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have plotted an histogram for the value 'Q' in my code below. I want the histogram to be from 0,1,2,3 format in the x-axis. At the movement I am not getting any value at 0. Ideally I want it to be shifted to the left and have the same plot starting from 0.

```
%Queue Buffer%
N = 1000; 
Q = zeros(N,1); 
Q2= 0; 
s = 20; 
for Ti = 2:N
  Q(Ti) = Q2;
  a = randi([0 32],1);
  a1 = a - s; 
  a2 = Q(Ti) + a1; 
  Q2 = max(0,a2); 
 end
t = 0:N-1;
xout=hist(Q,9);
bar(xout, 'barwidth', 1, 'basevalue', 0);
```

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Photos/qbuff.jpg?w=50ea6776

Comment: replace `9` with `t`, or whatever range you want.

Comment: I want the x-axis values to be from 0. That is 0,1,2,3 etc. When I do my current plot its coming as 1,2,3,etc not starting from 0. I want the current figure exacly like that but starting from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bar([0:length(xout)-1], xout, 'barwidth', 1, 'basevalue', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
hist(Q,t);
```

Or

```
xout=hist(Q,t);
bar(t,xout);
```